# Issue with MacBook on Boot

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, ssd

I have a 2012 MacBook Pro 13" with a 500 gb SSD

the SSD is about 1 year old and it was performing excellent, but now i dont know

Sometimes when i turn off the Mac and turn it on again im experiencing the Prohibitory sign on boot, i usually wait and sometimes the apple logo reappears or flashes a few times and then prohibitory sign appears again, sometimes i wait a few seconds and then it boots as normal

I have performed a Hardware test and it doesnt show any problem. I have reinstalled the OS a few times, SMART status is OK and i checked the disk with First aid on Disk Utility

Altough it always boots up, the prohibitory sign is making me nervous because im about to sell the MacBook and i dont want anything  to spoil my selling, i want to sell an excellent product.

The RAM is also in good shape so it is not that.

I checked SATA cable to see if something was loose, but nothing.

Any other suggestion?

**EDIT 1**

Also, sometimes it stays black after a wake up and i have to power it off and on to be able to use it

Comment: Just to clarify, you have run First Aid on both the SSD and your boot volume? If you cannot boot into macOS, I would suggest you do this in Recovery mode.

Comment: Yes, i did it also to the boot volume, in Recovery mode.

It says there were some things to fix, but even after that it still happens

Comment: Was Disk Utility able to successfully repair the SSD? It may be best to erase the disk and reinstall macOS. Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Wasnt. I even reinstalled OS for like the 4th time. After the fresh installation, the prohibitory sign appeared, so i think it is a SATA cable failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be experiencing an HDD cable failure.  I've had to replace a few of them from 2009-2012 laptops.  They run about $40CAD on Amazon; you'll need your exact model number to find a compatible one.  To find that, hold option, and go to Apple > System Information.  Look for the Model ID, it'll be something like

> MacBookPro11,2

Good luck!